# angular 2 data maps like http://datamaps.github.io/

Tags: angular

I am trying to create data visualisations using maps. I want exactly a map shown http://datamaps.github.io/. I have tried many approaches to include maps in my angular 2 app, but nothing worked. I have tried Jquery-mapael but even it didn't integrated. So can anyone provide me info or example abount how to include a map in angular 2 app ?? Any map will work but it should be working

Answer (score 0):

You could integrate datamaps.io in your project - see this post for using 3rd party libraries in Angular 2. 
[angular 2 - adding 3rd party libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796961/angular-2-adding-3rd-party-libs)