# How to import third party module in angular2 using angular-cli project?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng2-bootstrap

How to import third party module in angular2 project using cli. Like [ng2-validation](https://github.com/yuyang041060120/ng2-validation) OR ng2-bootstrap etc. I have don't any idea for how to plugin third party module.

Like **(Note: Angular-cli don't use system js file)**:

```
(function(global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

[image]

Comment: There are too many [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796961/angular-2-adding-3rd-party-libs) and [tutorials](https://medium.com/@s_eschweiler/using-external-libraries-with-angular-2-87e06db8e5d1#.ckkp13tzq) about this.

Comment: Please, check  my updated question

Answer (score 4):

I have find this solutions.

I have don't configure any file. but, directly import my usual angular module.

**users.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { UsersComponent } from './component/users.component';
import { AddUsersComponent } from './component/add-user.component';
import { UsersListComponent } from './component/user-list.component';

import { UsersService } from './service/user.service';

import { usersRouting } from './users.route';
import { SharedModule }       from '../shared/shared.module';
import { CustomFormsModule } from 'ng2-validation'; // ====== My third party module ======

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    usersRouting,
    SharedModule,
    CustomFormsModule // ======= My third party module =========
  ],
  declarations: [UsersComponent,AddUsersComponent,UsersListComponent],
  providers:[UsersService]
})
export class UsersModule { }
```

**add-user.html**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="form-group">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" #password="ngModel" required [rangeLength]="[5, 10]">
          <div *ngIf="password?.errors && (password.dirty || password.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
                <div *ngIf="password?.errors?.required">
                     Password is required.
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="password?.errors?.rangeLength">
                     Please enter 5 to 10 character.
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

**rangeLength** is my third party module validation.

Comment: nice, self answer :)

Answer (score 2):

for the usage of any third party lib in angular cli you have to list down the file named `angular-cli-build.js`

```
var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');

module.exports = function (defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)',
      'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'jquery/dist/jquery.min.+(js|map)',
      'ng2-validation/**/*.+(js|map)    //here is new entry
    ]
  });
};
```

By giving the entry here it will copy your required files in the vendor folder from where you can use those in your project.

than after you can import the file in index.html file from vendor folder.

Comment: I have not found "angular-cli-build.js" file

Comment: see at the root level of app you find there this file

Comment: Hi Friends, I have upload my directory structure file..please check

Comment: which version of angular-cli you are using ?

Comment: "project": {
        "version": "1.0.0-beta.15",
        "name": "ngcli"
    },

Comment: @pradeep jain: hello friends

Comment: I tryed adding a angular-cli-build.js file to my project. The file is ignored. When I do 'ng --version' I get:
"It seems like you're using the newest version of the Angular CLI that uses webpack. This version does not require an angular-cli-build file, but your project has one. It will be ignored."
It looks like angular-cli-build file is deprecated. I'm using angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.16. node: 4.4.2. npm: 3.10.6.

Comment: And webpack 2.1.0-beta.22

Answer (score -3):

npm install --save @types/{package name e.g underscore}

Comment: the question is not regarding to packages.json