# Using vanilla js code in Angular 2 (angular-cli)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives, angular2-modules

I am trying to implement the **[Vanilla Tilt JS plugin](https://micku7zu.github.io/vanilla-tilt.js/)** in my project, but I can't even seem to find a way of using vanilla js imports in my project.

So far, I have tried using it as a directive, just like you would use a jQuery plugin by using `ElementRef` , `Input` etc. from `@angular/core`.

I have included the script in my `.angular-cli.json` file under `scripts:` directly from the **[npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vanilla-tilt)** that I have installed for Vanilla Tilt JS.

And I was thinking about using it as a directive, since it has its own `data-tilt` attribute like so:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[data-tilt]'
})
export class ParallaxDirective {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {

    }
}
```

But I can't find a way to do this, despite my efforts so far. I am new to Angular 2.

My question is:

***Is it possible to use a plain javasciprt plugin inside Angular 2 , and if possible , how can I implement the Vanilla-Tilt JS plugin?***

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796961/angular-2-adding-3rd-party-libs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to import Vinilla-tilt and use the element reference passed into the constructor.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

const VanillaTilt = require('vanilla-tilt');

@Directive({
    selector: '[data-tilt]'
})
export class ParallaxDirective {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
      VanillaTilt.init(el.nativeElement, {
        max: 25,
        speed: 400
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: The only thing missing here is the `el.nativeElement` that makes a reference to the DOM.